# SceneManager.LoadScene doesn't work on development mobile build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to build a Unity game on android/iOS by checking the development build option (so that I can use the profiler for debugging), but the SceneManager.LoadScene function doesn't work. I tried the scene name and index as the function parameters, but both didn't work.

It's important to note that the game works perfectly fine if I uncheck the development build option. I'm currently using Unity 2019.3.5.f1.

[image]

Edit:
I noticed that the scene loads without any problems when I run `SceneManager.LoadScene` from the `Start()` function. However, in most parts of my code, I run `SceneManager.LoadScene` from inside other functions, such as event handlers.

Here are a few code examples:

1. I run this function in `Awake()`. It reaches `SceneManager.LoadScene("Credentials");` then stops:

```
private void ConfirmGooglePlayerServicesRequirements()
    {
        Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
            var dependencyStatus = task.Result;
            if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available)
            {
                // Create and hold a reference to your FirebaseApp,
                // where app is a Firebase.FirebaseApp property of your application class.
                app = Firebase.FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;

                InitializeFirebase();

                if (!signedIn)
                    SceneManager.LoadScene("Credentials");

            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError(System.String.Format(
                  "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: {0}", dependencyStatus));
                // Firebase Unity SDK is not safe to use here.
            }
        });
    }
```

2. This is a Firebase function which is called whenever a user signs in/out. It invokes an event called `signedInEvent`, which is handled by a function in another script that runs `SceneManager.LoadScene`.

```
void AuthStateChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (auth.CurrentUser != user)
        {
            signedIn = user != auth.CurrentUser && auth.CurrentUser != null;
            if (!signedIn && user != null)
            {
                Debug.Log("Signed out " + user.UserId);
            }
            user = auth.CurrentUser;
            if (signedIn)
            {
                Debug.Log("Signed in " + user.UserId);

                displayName = user.DisplayName ?? "";
                emailAddress = user.Email ?? "";
                userId = user.UserId ?? "";
                signedInEvent.Invoke(displayName, emailAddress, userId);
            }
        }
    }
```

Notes:

- Scenes/FirstScene is enabled. It was disabled when I took the screenshot above because I was doing some tests.
- I got this error using adb (android debug bridge) a while ago when I ran the game in development mode. It might be related to this issue: `FindGameObjectWithTag can only be called from the main thread`

Thanks!

Comment: Does show any error log?

Comment: @TimChang adb didn't show any errors

Comment: Are you talking about `FirstScene`? It is disabled .. in general please add your code of what you are trying.

Comment: @derHugo No, I'm talking about running LoadScene from any script. The game works without any issues if I uncheck development build. But in that case, I won't be able to use the profiler.

Comment: So show your code you are using to run this from a script ...

Answer (score 1):

> FindGameObjectWithTag can only be called from the main thread

This is indeed related! Now that you posted your code:

`ContinueWith` might get called on a background thread. Most of the Unity API may only be called from the **main thread** otherwise it might either show an error such as the one you mentioned or sometimes it just fails silently.

---

In general this is often solved by something like e.g. [UnityMainThreadDispatcher](https://github.com/PimDeWitte/UnityMainThreadDispatcher).

However, specifically for Firebase there already exists an extension called [`ContinueWithOnMainThread`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/extensions/task-extension) in the `Firebase.Extensions` namespace which makes sure the callback code is actually executed in the main thread where the Unity API works.

> Extension methods for `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` and `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T>` that allow the continuation function to be executed on the main thread in Unity.

```
using Firebase.Extensions;

private void ConfirmGooglePlayerServicesRequirements()
{
    Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => {
        var dependencyStatus = task.Result;
        if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available)
        {
            // Create and hold a reference to your FirebaseApp,
            // where app is a Firebase.FirebaseApp property of your application class.
            app = Firebase.FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;

            InitializeFirebase();

            if (!signedIn)
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene("Credentials");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: {dependencyStatus}", this);
            // Firebase Unity SDK is not safe to use here.
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: How do I know which parts of the code are not called from the main thread? Also, could this error lead to game crashes?